# I don't jew out of paying my comeuppance

Tags: meaning, etymology, verbs, pejorative-language, offensive-language

In the Quentin Tarantino film, Kill Bill 2, there is a scene between Bill and Budd where Budd says

> I don't dodge guilt, and I don't jew out of paying my comeuppance

at around 2:28 in this [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMI1uQBHUpA). My question is what is the meaning of the verb, jew, in this context? The only fitting definition I found was from [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=jew%20out),

> to renege on an agreement

but I wanted to get a confirmation and perhaps more background on how the verb is used this way since I haven't normally heard the word in this kind of dialogue. Another definition I found was

> to bargain sharply with

from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jew). Although I believe that this definition is less appropriate than the Urban Dictionary definition, it could still fit into this setting.

Comment: A side question: I'm quite familiar with the expression "X got his comeuppance," but I've never heard anyone use the expression "X paid his comeuppance." I'm not even sure what it means, given that Merriam-Webster defines _comeuppance_ as "a deserved rebuke or penalty: DESSERTS."  You can pay a penalty of course, but you can't pay a rebuke or desserts—those are things you receive (as you can also receive a penalty). Has anyone encountered this expression outside _Kill Bill 2_? Or is this a case of Quentin Tarantino mugging the language for ersatz tough-guy patter?

Comment: @SvenYargs It sounds like "made-up" tough guy talk to me. Tarantino seems to have this leitmotif running through many of his films of the "killer as philospher".

Comment: @Cascabel: The pinnacle of literary criticism on the subject of hard-boiled repartee may be this exchange from the 1941 film version of _The Maltese Falcon_: WILMER COOK: Keep on riding me and they're gonna be picking iron out of your liver. SAM SPADE: The cheaper the crook, the gaudier the patter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an offensive and outdated usage of the word jew:

[jew (down)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jew%20down) (verb)

> offensive:
>   to induce (a seller) by haggling to lower his price :  get (a price or a sum) reduced by haggling

-Merriam Webster

> The [verb jew (down)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/jew) is also perceived as offensive, because it perpetuates the stereotype of the shrewd Jewish moneylender or haggler.

-Dictionary.com

jew SB (out) of STH (verb)

seeems to go even further, meaning to cheat someone completely.

The only reference I can find with this version of the verb is in the same one you quoted, Urban Dictionary.com

I do not recommend that you use this verb, as it is offensive.

Comment: I felt icky just writing this

Comment: I'd say in today's environment it is VERY offensive, and if a person's use was made aware of, it could likely effect their employment prospects even if used in jest many years before in a different context.  In today's environment even complimenting shrewdness or haggling skills would be seen by some as actively reinforcing a sentiment that would lead to discrimination (aka a hate-crime). Just because a portion of a group may still be able to laugh or take pride in a stereotypical trait  doesn't make it close to a safe topic to reflect on. (just in case a teen is reading this)

Comment: It's so offensive I would advocate blanking out the word in the question's title, as in f--k.

Comment: Thank you Cascabel, I would never use this word in everyday conversation for I understand that it's offensive. I didn't realize that the verb's meaning was meant to demean an entire group of people. I'm not sure why Tarantino or Michael Marsden (actor who played Budd) would use this word in this particular scene but I will put back the tags that you used earlier. I'm not sure how to best go about censoring the verb in question so if someone else wants to do it, you're welcome to do so.

Comment: @ChrisGong They are not playing very nice people in the film. I would leave the verb in the title as it would be difficult to decipher with only 2 letters. There is no way you could have known that it was offensive.

Comment: It's a Q&A site about language -- as long as we treat everything clinically and don't endorse anything, I see no problem with leaving the word uncensored. As others have said, it would also make the question much more unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51559/discussion-between-lambie-and-cascabel).